# How do I translate this `for` loop for the fish shell?

Tags: fish

I'm translating a script from Z shell to Fish, and I've got this one part I can't figure out how to translate:

```
  for (( i=0; i < $COLUMNS; i++ )); do
    printf $1
  done
```

The only documentation for `for` loops I can find in Fish is for [this kind](http://ridiculousfish.com/shell/user_doc/html/commands.html#for).  How would I do this in Fish?

Answer (score 53, accepted):

It appears that the Fish shell does not have that kind of `for` loop, but instead requires you to take a different approach.  (The philosophy is apparently to rely on as few syntactic structures and operators as possible, and do as much with commands as possible.)

Here's how I did it, although I assume there are better ways:

```
for CHAR in (seq $COLUMNS)
  printf $argv[1]
end
```

This appears inside a function, hence the `$argv[1]`.

Comment: This is right, except the variables should match: `for i in (seq $COLUMNS); printf $i; end`

Comment: @ridiculous_fish: actually the `$1` is something else passed to the function that this loop is in... I didn't realize at the time I posted this it should be `$argv[1]`.  I don't actually care about the $CHAR or $i, I was just using `seq` to print the character in `$argv[1]` across the screen, once in each column.   I'll update the answer...

Answer (score 16):

I believe the answer from @iconoclast is the correct answer here.

I am here just to give an (not better) alternative.

a brief search in fish shell seems suggest it provides a while-loop in a form of :

```
while true
        echo "Loop forever"
end
```

As in C/C++ 101, we learned that for loop can be (mostly) translated to a while loop by:

```
for (A; B; C) {
  D;
}
```

translates to

```
A;
while (B) {
  D;
  C;
}
```

That's what you can consider if the condition and "incrementation" is not a straight-forward one.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how:

You have to pull one command in **()** and not like bash there is no need for **DO** and **DONE**

```
 for i in (find . -name file1| grep .pdf);rm $i ;end
```